# log ship wizard in SQL 2012 Std not showing compression option

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, compression, log-shipping

I cannot find the compression option in the log shipping setting page. the version of the SQL is Microsoft SQL 2012 Std.

[image]

Comment: I can find the compression option in SQL 2014 std, is that means SQL 2012 std do not support Log Shipping Compression ? I cannot find any official page about this feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed from Microsoft , SQL 2012 Standard do not support Log Shipping Compression. only Enterprise Version comes with this feature